# Can you find the error in the 2nd line? "interface tokenRecipient.... "

Tags: solidity, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address_from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) public; }

contract tokenERC20 {

    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    unint public decimals = 18;
    unit256 public totalSupply;

    mapping(address=>unit256) balanceof;
    mapping(address=> mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Burn( address indexed from, uint256 value);



}
```

Comment: You should check the compiling errors in a compiler..the errors are so easy to detect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a missing space: "address_from" should be "address _from".

Then "uint" is misspelled several times as "unint" or "unit".

Fixed, compiling code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) public; }

contract tokenERC20 {

    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint public decimals = 18;
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    mapping(address=>uint256) balanceof;
    mapping(address=> mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Burn( address indexed from, uint256 value);



}
```